# IQueryable en VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Hola alguien podría explicarme como es que funciona IQueryable que lo uso directamente en VB.NET ??

Gracias.

```
Dim obj As IQueryable(Of AfipEscalaSuss)
```

Answer (score 0):

[IQueryable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable(v=vs.110).aspx) es una interfaz que te permite ejecutar consultas a un conjunto de datos.

```
   IQueryable<Order> result = context.Orders;
   //Se filtran todas las órdenes donde el id sea igual a 10248.
   IQueryable<Order> product = result.Where(x => x.OrderID == 10248);
   //Recorremos todas las órdenes filtradas en product y mostramos el nombre de barco.
   foreach (Order r in product)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(r.ShipName);
   }
```

Comment: Por que usaste el x=> ? o podias poner solamente x.OrderID ?
Podria usar un proceso almacenado en vez de un IQueyable ?

Comment: Porque Where() recibe como parámetro un delegado Func<TSource, bool> donde TSource corresponde al tipo de dato de la plantilla del IQueryable, en mi ejemplo sería Order, y bool sería el retorno del delegado. Por ende, 'x' siendo el argumento del delegado, tomaría el valor de cada 'Order' de 'result'. Para saber más sobre '=>' Puedes echar un vistazo a lo que son las expresiones Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

`IQueryable(Of T)` es una interfaz que permite almacenar una **expresión** que puede ser modificada antes de ser evaluada para obtener los datos.

Ejemplo utilizando Entity Framework

```vb
Dim query As IQueryable = db.Personas 'Aún no se traen los datos de la BD
query = query.Where(Function(p) p.Edad > 18) 'Todavía no se ejecuta la consulta
Dim resultados = query.ToList() 'Acá si se genera el SQL correspondiente y se traen los datos desde la BD
```